# Pulling leaflet marker coordinates in EJS Template

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I'm converting leaflet's latlng object of the current location to geoJSON, and pulling the coordinates as a string and saving them to the database by storing the value into an input.

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    var coordinatesNew = (e.latlng.lat.toString()) + ", " + (e.latlng.lng.toString());
    if (mymap.hasLayer(mark_by_input)) {
       mymap.removeLayer(mark_by_input);
    }
    if(mymap.hasLayer(mark_by_click)) {
        mark_by_click.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        mymap.panTo(e.latlng);
        $('.coords').val(coordinatesNew);
        console.log(coordinatesNew);
    } else {
      mark_by_click = new L.marker(e.latlng);
      mark_by_click.addTo(mymap)
      .bindPopup(e.latlng.toString());
      $('.coords').val(e.latlng);
      mymap.flyTo(e.latlng);
      var g = mark_by_click.toGeoJSON();
      var s = g.geometry.coordinates.reverse().toString();
      coordinatesNew = s;
      $('.coords').val(coordinatesNew);
      console.log(coordinatesNew);
     } 
}
```

Here is the GET route from the app.js, where I pull the collection from the database and then use it in my EJS file.

```
app.get('/events', function(req, res){
    Event.find({}, function(err, allevents){
       if(err) {
           console.log('Error!');
       } else {
           res.render('eventDisplay', {events:allevents});
       }
    });
});
```

And here is the EJS snippet where I apply some DB information

```
<div class="info-container">
 <% events.forEach(function(event){ %>
   <div>
    <ul>    
     <li><a href="/event/<%= event._id %>"><strong>Author: <%=event.author%></strong> | <%=event.name%></a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% }); %>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through and apply a L.marker.addTo(myMap) using my <%=event.coordinates%>, however my leaflet mapInit() containing the leaflet objects is not communicating with my EJS file, and without that get route, I'm not sure how to use my DB information within the leaflet functions in my JS file.

Comment: I don't believe you can use Leaflet on the server. That might preclude an answer to your problem, but you'll likely have to render all of this on the client.

Comment: You should set up a 2nd route that serves the events as a JSON array. You can use AJAX to request it on page load, and render the map from there.

Comment: For reference what @djfdev is saying is the correct approach here and this should be separate to the template render or to alternately render the JSON string within a `<script>` tag so it can evaluate to the local context. Separate would be cleaner, if an extra call. Also for reference, none of the other tagged technology stack nor code included in the question really apply to the question being asked. When posting here, try to consider that the question and content should be specific to the actual issue. In this case, using the data for the script library methods.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and advice guys! The simplest solution I found was to store the coordinates in a global array via the EJS template and iterate through them within the javascript file containing the leaflet functions and apply them to markers.